# Difference between "o" and "u" to say "or"

Tags: traducción, significado-en-contexto

I have seen **o** used most commonly as the Spanish word for "or". I am wondering if this can be used interchangeably with the new word for "or" that I discovered, **u**. By interchangeably I mean I would imagine "esto u aquello" and "esto o aquello" should mean the same right? Both should translate to "this or that".

Recently I say **u** used in this context: Yo me duermo siete u ocho horas cada noche. Yo no duermo en la clase.

Comment: As an additional point, "y" and "e" follow the same rules as "o" and "u". For example, "izquierda y derecha" and "derecha e izquierda" or "fuí e hice eso".

Comment: "Esto u aquello" is simply incorrect, although people will understand you, whereas  "cinco o  ocho" is incorrect  and maybe they won't understand you. Try to say  "cinco o ocho" speaking loudly and fas. People will listen "cincooocho" and they  will say "Sorry, what have you said? Vocalize better, please."). Then  you will be heard like a howler monkey trying to make clear interword pauses  ("cinc oh -- oh  -- oh cho"). However, you can pronounce "cinco u ocho" as a single word ("cincouocho") and everybody will understand you, You should not use "o" here because it is cacophonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Siempre tenés que usar la **o**, excepto en los casos en los que el fonema inicial de la siguiente palabra sea también /o/ ([referencia](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/cambio-de-la-o-disyuntiva-en-u-0)). En esta última situación, con el fin de evitar la cacofonía que se produce al  tener que pronunciar dos /o/es seguidas, se emplea **u**. Ejemplos:

> Puede ser manzana **o** pera, no tengo preferencia por ninguna fruta en particular.

> Los políticos deciden el destino de nuestro país por las medidas que toman, ya sea por acción **u** omisión.

> No importa que sean homónimos **u** homófonos, esas palabras tienen un significado diferente.

> Esa vez fuimos siete **u** ocho, no recuerdo bien.

> Esa vez fuimos 7 **u** 8, no recuerdo bien.

Así que, para tu ejemplo, lo correcto es ‘esto o aquello’.

Answer (score 3):

**Real Academia Española** - ESPAÑOL AL DÍA

> [Cambio de la «o» disyuntiva en «u»](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/cambio-de-la-o-disyuntiva-en-u-0)
> La conjunción disyuntiva o toma la forma u ante palabras que empiezan por el sonido vocálico /o/ (o- u ho- en la escritura): *unos **u** otros, minutos u horas, ordenar u organizar*.
>
> Cuando la conjunción disyuntiva o va seguida de una expresión numérica que *empieza por la cifra 8, como 8, 80, 81, 800, etc*., también debe adoptar la forma u, tanto en la lectura como en la escritura, porque las palabras que representan estas cifras (ocho, ochenta, ochenta y uno, ochocientos...) empiezan por el sonido /o/: 700 u 800.
>
> La conjunción o también se transforma en u si la palabra que sigue comienza por /o/ en las correlaciones disyuntivas, en las que aparece una conjunción ante cada una de las opciones posibles: *Los hornos antiguos eran o circulares **u** ovalados; La disyuntiva era clara: **u** obteníamos beneficios pronto o habría que cerrar la empresa*.

Bolding mine. This is straight from the horse's mouth.

Interesting point: In Spanish they say disjunctive where we could say a conjunction. Funny, huh? The Spanish actually is more logical as "or" does separate and does not join. :)

Comment: Interestingly logicians do call it disjunctive or but that is jargon not everyday common-or-garden English.

Comment: @mdewey You are so right about that.

Answer (score 2):

Usar "u" en vez de "o" se usa cuando la próxima palabra empiece con el sonido de la letra 'o'.  E.g. Uno u otro.

Lo mismo aplica al uso de "e" en vez de "y" cuando la próxima palabra empiece con el sonido de la letra 'i'.  E.g. Sinagogas e iglesias.